# using realloc with a NULL pointer

Tags: c, realloc, null-pointer

Is this valid in c?

```
int  func()
{                                                               
        static int *p = NULL;
        p = realloc(p, 20);                             
        return 0;
}
```

I want to use this in recursion so every time the `func` function is called if there is already allocated memory it will be reallocated and if there is non(first call) it will be allocated instead.

Comment: `p` is not a null pointer -- it's uninitialized. I think you want `static int*p;`

Comment: What you describe _is_ valid, but your code does _not_ match what you describe because you did not initialize `p` at all.

Comment: You should change `int *p;` to `static int *p;` to have it do what you want. `static` make the variable retained between multiple calls of `func` and initialized to zero by default.

Comment: Instead of static I would rather pass the pointer down to recursive calls as a parameter. This will make the function pure and reentrant. Don't forget to free it.

Comment: okay I did fix the code now

Comment: That works - assuming you have no thread contention issues that need to be resolved with a mutex. Unless you're doing low-level stuff, this is a code smell. Note that an empty parameter list specification: `func ()` should *not* be used in modern C. Use: `func (void)`

Comment: `is called if there is already allocated memory it will be reallocated` Why would you want to reallocate to the same `20` amount of memory? The memory is yours, just use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `realloc()` with `NULL` for the first argument is legal and `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, but your code is illegal because it is using an value of uninitialized non-static local variable `p`, which is indeterminate.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.22.3.5 The realloc function:

> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> 3 If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size.